# Why is $e^{iAt/n} = I + \frac{1}{n} i A t + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Currently, I am reading Section 4.7.2 of [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information: 10th Anniversary Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107002176) by Nielson et. al.

In the proof of Theorem 4.3, the authors have mentioned that:

$$e^{iAt/n} = I + \frac{1}{n} i A t + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

where, $A$ is a Hermitian operator and $n$ is a positive integer.

I would like to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the matrix exponential?

Comment: @Batman, I guess, it is $$e^X = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} X^k$$ as per the Wiki article. Here, $X$ is the matrix.

Comment: Okay, so, from that, where are you having difficulty to conclude the desired statement?

Comment: @Batman, I can follow it now from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^{sB}=I+sB+s^2( \frac{B^2}{2!}+s \frac{B^3}{3!}+...)$ and $\frac{B^2}{2!}+s \frac{B^3}{3!}+... \to \frac{B^2}{2!}$ for $s \to 0$.